# Passign multiple columns to an apply: TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone help me solve this error or give me a clue what is going on? We are trying to get multiple data columns into an apply().

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.set_option('display.max_columns',None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows',None)

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df['modification_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['modification_date'])
df = df[['transaction_amount','transaction_direction','branch_code','user_code', 'modification_date']]

def myfunction(grouped_df):
    print(grouped_df)
    return grouped_df['transaction_amount'].sort_values(ascending = False).head(5)

df = df.groupby(['transaction_direction'])[["transaction_amount",'user_code']].apply(myfunction)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marijana/archiconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 859, in apply
    result = self._python_apply_general(f, self._selected_obj)
  File "/home/marijana/archiconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 895, in _python_apply_general
    keys, values, not_indexed_same=mutated or self.mutated
  File "/home/marijana/archiconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 1279, in _wrap_applied_output
    return self._concat_objects(keys, values, not_indexed_same=True)
  File "/home/marijana/archiconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 1167, in _concat_objects
    result.name = self._selection_name
  File "/home/marijana/archiconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5152, in __setattr__
    return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
  File "/home/marijana/archiconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 495, in name
    raise TypeError("Series.name must be a hashable type")
TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marijana/main.py", line 21, in <module>
    df = df.groupby(['transaction_direction'])[["transaction_amount",'user_code']].apply(myfunction)
  File "/home/marijana/archiconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 870, in apply
    return self._python_apply_general(f, self._selected_obj)
  File "/home/marijana/archiconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 895, in _python_apply_general
    keys, values, not_indexed_same=mutated or self.mutated
  File "/home/marijana/archiconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 1279, in _wrap_applied_output
    return self._concat_objects(keys, values, not_indexed_same=True)
  File "/home/marijana/archiconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 1167, in _concat_objects
    result.name = self._selection_name
  File "/home/marijana/archiconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5152, in __setattr__
    return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
  File "/home/marijana/archiconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 495, in name
    raise TypeError("Series.name must be a hashable type")
TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type
```

Stackoverflow says I have to add more information here but I am really not sure what to add.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood what you would like to calculate (get transaction_amount and user_code by top 5 values of transaction_amount within each group of transaction_direction) you can use following approach without using of apply method:

```
df.sort_values(by=['transaction_direction', 'transaction_amount'], ascending=False) \
  .groupby(by='transaction_direction') \
  .head(5)[['transaction_direction', 'user_code', 'transaction_amount']]
```